# Keep values in a particular column based on priority and remove the other values for each row

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, r

On giving this command, I am getting like this

```
awk '{print $7}' myfile.txt

/myfolder/1001.AB.txt.gz,/myfolder/1001.CD.txt.gz
/myfolder/1011.filtered.txt,/myfolder/1011.AB.txt.gz,myfolder/1011.CD.txt.gz
/myfolder/1003.AB.txt.gz,/myfolder/1003.CD.txt.gz
/myfolder/1024.merged.txt.gz,/myfolder/1024.filtered.txt,/myfolder/1024.AB.txt.gz,/myfolder/1024.CD.txt.gz
/myfolder/1014.merged.txt.gz
/myfolder/1020.AB.txt.gz,/myfolder/1020.CD.txt.gz
/myfolder/1021.filtered.AB.txt.gz,/myfolder/1021.merged.CD.txt.gz
/myfolder/1031.filtered.txt
```

But I want like this 
Priority is [1] `merged.txt.gz`, [2] `AB.txt.gz`&`CD.txt.gz`, [3] `filtered.txt`
Based on priority keep the values and remove the other values In  **[2] AB.txt.gz** & **CD.txt.gz** keep both values

---

**OUTPUT**

```
/myfolder/1001.AB.txt.gz,/myfolder/1001.CD.txt.gz
/myfolder/1011.AB.txt.gz,/myfolder/1011.CD.txt.gz
/myfolder/1003.AB.txt.gz,/myfolder/1003.CD.txt.gz
/myfolder/1024.merged.txt.gz
/myfolder/1014.merged.txt.gz
/myfolder/1020.AB.txt.gz,/myfolder/1020.txt.CD.gz
/myfolder/1021.merged.txt.gz
/myfolder/1031.filtered.txt
```

Comment: show your current `awk '{print $0}' myfile.txt`

Comment: its tab separated file with. awk '{print $0}' printing all columns with serial number, name, class( in my file).  $7 is my last column. **awk '{print $NF}' myfile.txt** this also gives the same as  awk '{print $7}' myfile.txt

Comment: could there be multiple `merged.txt.gz` items, like `/myfolder/1031.filtered.txt, /myfolder/1032.filtered.txt` ? If so, should they be collapsed?

Comment: elaborate, why this `1021.merged.CD.txt.gz` should become eventually `/myfolder/1021.merged.txt.gz`? What if there would be item `1021.merged.CD.filter111.txt.gz` ?

Comment: In a row, if `merged.txt.gz` comes once it won't come again. @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: there was one more question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404952/keep-values-in-a-particular-column-based-on-priority-and-remove-the-other-values#comment724261_404952. Elaborate your replacement logic

Comment: @bioinform You seem to describe just what my script performs, so does it solve your task or what is different than expected?

Comment: No merging,  removing other items based on priority. `myfolder/1024.merged.txt.gz,/myfolder/1024.filtered.txt,/myfolder/1024.AB.txt.gz,/myfolder/1024.CD.txt.gz` becomes like this  **/myfolder/1024.merged.txt.gz** @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/.*<TAB>//;/merged.txt.gz/!b2
  s/,*[^,]*AB.txt.gz,*//g;s/,*[^,]*CD.txt.gz,*//g
  :1
  s/,*[^,]*filtered[^,]*,*//g;b
  :2
  /AB.txt.gz/b1
  /CD.txt.gz/b1' myfile.txt
```

How it works:

- As you only need the last of TAB-separated colmuns, the leading `s/.*`<kbd>TAB</kbd>`//` removes everything upto and including the last TAB. Note that you may have to enter ctrl-v before the TAB in your shell. Or for GNU `sed`, use `\t` instead of a literal TAB.
- If there is `merged.txt.gz` in that line, the jump to mark `2` (`b2`) is not performed because of the `!`, so the second line of the script removes `AB` and `CD` items and the fourth line removes `filtered` items, before the `b` without mark jumps to the end of the script.
- If there is no `merged.txt.gz` in that row, the first line sends us to mark `:2`, then if there is `AB.txt.gz`, the 6th line send us to mark `:1` to remove the `filtered` items, or if there is `CD.txt.gz`, the last line does the same
- If there is neither `merged` nor `AB` not `CD`, the row is output untouched.

This produces the output for your given input (except for one slash that is already missing in line 2 of your input). You can modify it to match your original input.

If it's not always the last column, but always the 7th, instead of `s/.*`<kbd>TAB</kbd>`//` use `s/\([^`<kbd>TAB</kbd>`]`<kbd>TAB</kbd>`\}\{6\}//;s/`<kbd>TAB</kbd>`.*//` to remove the first six and all trailing columns.

Comment: `Awesome man. But where you are giving column number and how do i give column number as i have in 7th column . Its working.

Comment: Updated to remove everything but the last column from the input.

Comment: Thank u sir. Can you refer any book or something for good practice of `sed`?

Comment: One question what if i have `filtered.txt` word in every line then how do i write this line `s/,*[^,]*filtered[^,]*,*//g;b`.

Comment: like this `/myfolder/1024.merged.filtered.txt.gz,/myfolder/1024.filtered.txt,/myfolder/1024.AB.filtered.txt.gz,/myfolder/1024.CD.filtered.txt.gz`

Comment: So the lines you want to keep also include `filtered`? So what is unique about those that should be removed? Do they always have a number before the `.filtered`? Then write that line as `s/,*[^,]*[0-9]\.filtered[^,]*,*//g;b`